# Spring Boot Autoconfigured ObjectMapper plus additional ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-web

We are currently trying to implement a JSON Logging library making use of spring auto configuration or create its Jackson ObjectMapper. Our aim is to not override the spring auto configuration in class `JacksonAutoConfiguration` so that every customization by clients of the logging library won't be disabled.

The actual spring behavior is bean based and our main problem is that the `JacksonProperties` are not customizable and reusable for us. If we actually add a second bean of `JacksonProperties` the application start up would fail because `JacksonAutoConfiguration.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class` won't be able to handle a second bean. (The Spring Boot internal one is not annotated as `@Primary`.)

So what we did was start reimplementing every bean like the builder, customizer and so on. But this is not very maintainable as it duplicates framework code.

Our question now is if there would be any way to adapt the way of creating data sources for jackson object mapper beans. An example of creating data sources would be a following one.

```
@Bean(name = "testDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.datasource")
public HikariDataSource naeDataSource(DataSourceProperties testDataSourceProperties) {
    return testDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}
```

We know the problem would still be that overriding the object mapper would deactivate it but if you pay attention to the application context it would be much easier to offer multiple object mapper instances.

Or is there any easier or other way we did not find so far?

Versions used:
Spring-Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE

**UPDATE**

I forked the spring boot project, made some changes to `Spring Boot Autoconfiguration` module and also set up a small demo project. I do not think it is the perfect way but with this changes it would be possible to initialize own object mapper easily from configuration properties. For example you can now easily create five object mapper for five different rest templates and clients called via REST-API.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "logging.jackson")
@Bean("loggingJacksonProperties")
public JacksonProperties loggingJacksonProperties() {
    return new JacksonProperties();
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper secondObjectMapper(@Qualifier("loggingJacksonProperties") JacksonProperties loggingJacksonProperties) {
    return loggingJacksonProperties.initializeJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().build();
}
```

Comparing-Fork: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/compare/2.1.x...mixaaaa:feature/jackson_properties_initializer

Demo-Project: https://github.com/mixaaaa/jackson-demo

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do – in particular I didn't understand the connection between creating DataSources and ObjectMappers – but have you considered not exposing the `ObjectMapper` that's used by the JSON logging library as a bean?

Comment: Why we need our object mapper as an bean is because we want to have our lib customizable by every user. It is an shared library and if one user wants to have null values in his logging output then it should be possible to enable this feature via application properties as he knows it from standard spring configuration.

And the handling of datasources was just an smart example for us of the way creating beans easily from properties.

Comment: The `ObjectMapper` could be customised via properties without the `ObjectMapper` itself being a bean.

Comment: Yes, got your point. But it would be impossible to reuse the `JacksonProperties` and customizing features from your already implemented builder. Or am I wrong? At least i would need a bean for the properties which would lead to duplicate bean exception?

Comment: small update with example projects :)